# Default GNOME apps give "Error flushing display" on Wayland

Tags: debian, gnome, nvidia, wayland

I'm using Debian testing and after I last updated my machine many GNOME default apps stopped working on Wayland.

In particular `gnome-software`, `gnome-control-center` and `gnome-calculator` give all the same output when launching:

```
Gdk-Message: 15:15:14.400: Error flushing display: Protocol error
```

And after this massage the app immediately crashes.

If I run the app on x11 with `env GDK_BACKEND=x11 gnome-control-center` for example the programs works as expected leading me to think is a Wayland related problem.

How can make those app work on Wayland?

#### System info:

- OS: Debian bookworm (testing)
- DE: GNOME 42.0
- NVIDIA Drivers: 470.103.01-3

Comment: I seem to have a similar issue, I just have Intel GPU. The `GDK_BACKEND` workaround worked for me. 
```(gnome-control-center:112028): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 11:27:22.750: invalid cast from 'GdkWaylandDisplay' to 'GdkX11Display'
Xlib: request 3 length 8 would exceed buffer size.
Xlib: request 14 length 8 would exceed buffer size.
[xcb] Extra reply data still left in queue
[xcb] This is most likely caused by a broken X extension library
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
gnome-control-center: ../../src/xcb_io.c:673: _XReply: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_extra_reply_data_left' failed.
Aborted```

Comment: Just some screens in gnome-control-center seem to trigger it. E.g. Multitasking but not Sound, that might be a clue. When switching to Multitasking, I would get: ```(gnome-control-center:112639): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 11:31:37.321: invalid cast from 'GdkWaylandDisplay' to 'GdkX11Display'
Segmentation fault```